# How I can send multiple checkboxes included in a table

Tags: php, mysql, html, web

I have a table and it contains more than one column, and one of columns is to check/select all checkboxes in my table rows, actually I can select one or multiple checkboxes if I want from the checkboxes that are in the rows.

I have searched and found this result:
[multiple checkboxes with php in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877256/multiple-checkboxes-with-php-in-table)
but it's not helpful, and I couldn't understand it completely.

What I want from my code to do is:
When I select one or multiple checkboxes, then when I click on (Publish) button -the code for the button is down below within the page code- the page should receive the selected values from the checkboxes and send them to the same page (article?do=pub&articleid='.$fileid)

---

This is the code:

```
<?php 
    $Title = 'Manage Approved Articles';
    include 'init.php';
    $AdminName = $_SESSION['username'];
    // Check if user is the Admin or not
    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND isAdmin = 1');
    $stmt->execute(array($AdminName));
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($count > 0) { }  else {
        header('Location: ../index');
        exit();
    }
    ?>
        <section class="Cust-container">
    <?php
      $do = isset($_GET['do']) ? $_GET['do'] : 'article';
      if($do == 'article') { echo 
      '<h2 class="heading">Manage Articles</h2>'; ?>
      <!-- Manage Articles Page -->
        <table class="admin-article-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
              <th width="41%">Article Title</th>
              <th width="18%">Category</th>
              <th width="10%">By</th>
              <th width="10%">Publish
                <input style="height: 20px; width: 20px;margin-left: 7px"
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="checkAll">
              </th>
              <th width="21%">Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <?php
      // retrieving data from db
      $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE Approved = 1');
      $stmt->execute();
      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

      if(empty($rows)) { echo
      '<tr>
        <td class="empty" colspan="5">There\'re No Approved Articles</td>
       </tr>'; 
      } else {
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $fileid       = $row['FileID'];
      $filedir      = $row['FileDirectory'];
      $catID        = $row['CatID'];
      $F_name       = array_shift(explode('.', $row['FileName']));
      $full_fname = $row['FileName']; 
      $uploaderId = $row['User_ID']; echo 
      '<tr>
        <td>' . $row['ArticleTitle'] . '</td>';?>
        <?php
            $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM cats WHERE ID = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($catID));
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            if(empty($rows)) {
                echo "<td class='empty'>No Declared Category</td>";
            } else {
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    $category = $row['Category'];
                } echo '
                        <td>'.$category.'</td>
                ';
            }
        echo '<td>';?>
            <?php
            $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT FullName FROM users WHERE UserID = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($uploaderId));
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo $row['FullName'];
             } echo '
             </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Publ[]"
                    value="'.$fileid.'" class="chk" required>
                </td>
                    <td>';?>
                <?php echo '
            <a class="option-del" style="margin-left: 12%;float:left" href="?do=delete&fileid='.$fileid.'&fullName='.$full_fname.' "onclick="return ConfirmContin(this);">Delete</a>
            <a class="option" style="float:left;margin-right: -30px" href="?do=unapprove&fileid='.$fileid.'&filename='.$F_name.'&fullnm='.$full_fname.'" onclick="return ConfirmContin(this);">Unapprove</a>
            <br><br><br>
            <form method="post" action="?do=updateCat&fileid='.$fileid.'">
            <select name="cats">';
                 $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM cats');
                 $stmt->execute();
                 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
                 if(empty($rows)) {
                    echo "<option>-- No Categories Found --</option>";
                 } else {
                    echo "<option value='0' Title='delete the article from its chosen category'>Make as Uncategorized</option>";
                    foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        $catid   = $row['ID'];
                        $catname = $row['Category'];
                        echo '<option value='.$catid.'>'.$catname.'</option>';
                    }   
                 } echo '</select><input type="submit" style="width:130px;height:40px;border-color:#777;background-color:#444;color:#FFF" value="Update"></form>
        </td>
       </tr>
       ';  
       }
      }
        ?>
            </tbody>
            <tr><td colspan="3"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Publish" name="publish"
                style="width:130px;height:40px;border-color:#090B64;
                background-color:#475590;color:#FFF">
            </td>
            <td></td></tr>
        </table>
        </section>
        <?php
      } elseif ($do == 'pub') {
            // Some Code for handling the sent values (sent by clicking on Publish button) from the selected checkboxes that exists in the table rows
        } else {
            header('Location: ../index');
            exit();
        } ?>

    <?php 
    include $tpl . 'footer.php';
    ?>
```

This is a screen shot of the table:

[Table for checking multiple checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLsm1.png)

I am a beginner and I don't know a lot about php and handling requests (get and post).
if I didn't clarify my question enough please ask me in which point I didn't, so you can fully understand my problem and help me solving it hopefully.

So much of thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want (ie give a hypothetical example where this would actually work)

Comment: @cullub
I want to get the values of the selected checkboxes when I click the button (Publish) , and I found it difficult because the button and the checkboxes are separated from each others so I can't put them in a form tag , because the inputs (Checkboxes) are inside the table and the button is in different row of the table.
So the simple question is :

How I can get the checkboxes values when I click on Publish button :

`<input type="submit" value="Publish" name="publish" style="width:130px;height:40px;border-color:#090B64; background-color:#475590;color:#FFF">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `form`.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) does a pretty good job of describing how forms work, but I'll go over it quickly here as well.

The HTML `<form>` element defines a form that is used to collect user input.  You'd put a `form` around your table, so every `input` inside your table would get sent when you click your submit button (in this case publish).  If you're using a GET, the data will be sent in the link text after the question mark, and if you use a POST, it won't use the link address.  Basically if you are going to change something (like publish your article), you'll want to use POST. ([What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)).

You'll access the value of the checkbox after the user clicks submit.  When he does that, it'll sent all the information to the form's `action` value - or if it doesn't have one, then directly to the same page, where you'll do the processing before showing the updated info.  E.g. `<form action="myActionPage.php" method="POST">` will send all the info inside that form via `POST` to `myActionPage.php`.  Inside `myActionPage.php`, you'll access your checkbox values like so: `$_POST['checkboxName']`.  If you want to access multiple checkboxes of the same name, use `$_POST['checkboxName'][]` - it's an array of the checkboxes.  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997271/3437608 does an excelent job explaining this)

Once you've gotten the values, check to see whether `isset($_POST['checkboxName'])` - if true, then checkbox was checked.  ([How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php))

Then you can happily publish the page, and direct the user either back to the admin page you showed, or the page they just published.

Good Luck!